# 64bit Hardware support

Tags: 64-bit

I am using C2D processor which supports EM64T instructions. Is that all what is required for running 64 bit OS and applications?

Or what actually is required for running x64?

Comment: ok. let us be specific - what is the difference in 64-bit and 32-bit processors HARDWAREwise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primarily all you need is a processor that claims AMD64 or EM64T compatability in order to run a 64-bit OS.  There are a number of newer functions available on newer 64 bit processors like AMD-V or similar for virtualisation (running another OS within your current OS) but they are not needed to run a 64-bit OS.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit on an early generation AMD X2 64-bit processor and it works fine, you should have no problem with a C2D.

64-bit simply allows a much larger address space so that the computer can use more RAM **effectively**.  Ignoring the fact that a 32-bit computer could **in theory** see more than 4GB of RAM it will not be as effective as using it as a full 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any CPU that supports Intel EM64T or AMD64 (such as your Core 2 Duo) is capable of running 64-bit Windows, Linux, and other "x64" 64-bit operating systems.  EM64T and AMD64 are specific implementations of the x86-64 instruction set originally specified by AMD as a 64-bit extension to the x86 instruction set.  This expanded instruction set includes additional 64-bit registers and uses a 64-bit memory address space.  The term x86-64 has since been shortened to x64 for simplicity.

There are also other competing 64-bit architectures, such as Sun's SPARC platform and Intel's Itanium platform, but these are incompatible with EM64T/AMD64, and have only been used for server- or workstation-grade computers, rather than consumer-targeted PCs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a 64-bit Windows OS, run the **[Windows 7 Upgrade advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15&displaylang=en)**; it will tell you whether your computer meets the requirements for 64-bit or not.

[image]

As for your new question:

**[The difference between 64 and 32 bit processors](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/windowsxp/articles/581/1/The-difference-between-64-and-32-bit-processors)**

Comment: No i dont want to know about upgradation, i just want to know the hardware requirements of 64 OS in detail. thanks

Comment: the hardware requirements are different for each OS, since you don't tell which 64-bit OS you have in mind, the is no general answer.

Comment: question updated. please see comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,a 64-bit processor is what's required for running an 64-bit OS,the other requirements differ according to the OS itself

Answer (score 1):

In short: 64-bit processor got registers to store and operate on 64bit data and addresses.